# Checkbox to toggle all selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have this javascript code

```
    // Listen for click on toggle checkbox
$('#select-all').click(function(event) {   
    if(this.checked) {
        // Iterate each checkbox
        $(':checkbox').each(function() {
            this.checked = true;                        
        });
    }
});
```

And I have this

```
<form action="" method="POST">    
Toggle All : &nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" name="select-all" id="select-all" />
```

then at my table I have multiple checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-1" id="checkbox-1" value="1"> Select
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-2" id="checkbox-2" value="2"> Select
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-3" id="checkbox-3" value="3"> Select
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-4" id="checkbox-4" value="4"> Select
```

When I click on toggle all, it does not check checkbox-1 to checkbox-4

What went wrong in my javascript code.

Thanks!! I want to actually do a function that will send all the value of checkbox1-4 by post when they are checked on form submit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply do like this.

```
$('#select-all').click(function(event) {
    $(':checkbox').prop("checked", this.checked);
});
```

You do not need to loop through each checkbox to check all.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/1s22gcL5/16/)

Wrap the code in dom ready if your script is in head tag

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#select-all').click(function(event) {
        $(':checkbox').prop("checked", this.checked);
    });
});
```

Comment: I like the way you did.

Comment: @Anoop Joshi , I tried your method but doesnt' work. I know your fiddle works but when I implement same code, it doesn't work, is there any file I need to run when using this method like jquery min or anything?